Create unique key/hash based on object
Say I have the following JavaScript objects:
const obj1 = {
 key1: 'str1',
 key2: 'str2'
}

const obj2 = {
 key2: 'str2',
 key1: 'str1'
}

const obj3 = {
 key1: 'something else',
 key2: 'str2'
}

const obj4 = {
 differentKey: 'str1',
 key2: 'str2'
}

I'd like to create a unique key based on a given object. This is so I can properly cache some data related to each object in a Map structure. In this scenario, obj1 and obj2 should have the same key, as the only difference is the ordering of properties. obj3 and obj4 should have different keys from each other. I tried using JSON.stringify() but this gives different results for obj1 and obj2 due to the ordering. Is there a way to get around this?
I will accept an answer that handles only primitive types, but something that handles non-primitive types will also be accepted and would be great!

Please share your attempt using JSON.stringify()

If JSON.stringify is acceptable for you, that sounds like the "key" being long is no concern, while even a one trillionth chance of a clash is? Also, what kind of properties can these be? For example, generating a key for symbol properties sounds like a real challenge (impossible?).

@mykaf That seems unnecessary; it's trivial to reproduce by calling JSON.stringify on any two objects with keys in different order.

@MarkBaijens It's similar, but does not answer how to generate a hash for the object ignoring the order of keys. It should not be the responsibility of the asker to differentiate their question from every other similar question on Stack Overflow.

the complexity of the answer depends on the complexity of the actual objects you'll be dealing with. The trivial examples in the question are easily handled.

@Unmitigated From how I understand it the OP tries to solve the problem of comparing objects in Javascript. He suggests a hash might be one of the ways to solve it. However I don't think a hash will be useful looking at how objects work. Therefore the duplicate is very suitable in my opinion.

@MarkBaijens The question only mentions caching data related to objects, e.g. in a hash map structure. Unless you suggest comparing a key with every other key in the map, that does not fully answer the question.

Well reducing any arbitrary object to a hash is going to require specialized code to deal with particular data structures. What are the properties that should contribute to the hash? Which shouldn't? What parts of an object graph are relevant? How are functions to be compared? How are cycles to be handled? There's no single answer to this other than to say that the simplest possible way of differentiating "key" objects is probably a good starting point.

Hi all, thanks for your comments! I want to clarify that I'll accept an answer that only handles primitive types in a flat object. However, I didn't want to discourage anyone from posting a solution that handles more complex types like functions, or nested structures.

To answer @Unmitigated, yes, I need a key that I can use in a Map instance

@Matt That clarification should be edited into the question itself.

@MarkBaijens "However I don't think a hash will be useful looking at how objects work. Therefore the duplicate is very suitable in my opinion." you're just trying to answer a different question than the one asked. If you don't know, ask for clarification. And consider closing as unclear if it can't really be answered. However, don't just close as question about A as B. If a future visitor searches how to hash an object (A) they would not be served by how to compare objects (B). By making the decision for OP, you are also claiming all queries about A are actually about B.

Here's a function that recursively sorts nested objects by key. Then you can use JSON.stringify to create the unique keys.
Feel free to fine tune the object type check (isObject) to fit your needs.
Edit: As VLAZ mentioned, JSON.stringify can exclude certain value types. Namely, a function, symbol, or undefined. I've updated the example to handle undefined and if required, you can expand the replacer function to handle functions and symbols too.


function sort(object) {
  const sortedEntries = Object.entries(object).sort((a, b) =>
    a[0].localeCompare(b[0])
  );

  const withSortedValues = sortedEntries.map(([key, value]) => {
    const isObject = typeof value === 'object' && value !== null
    const newVal = isObject ? sort(value) : value;
    return [key, newVal];
  });

  return Object.fromEntries(withSortedValues);
}

// Edit: Replacer function to keep undefined values
// and replace them with a placeholder. Feel free to
// change the placeholder to your needs (another string or null)
function replacer(k,v) {
  return v === undefined ? "[undefined]" : v;
}

function compare(obj1, obj2) {
  return JSON.stringify(sort(obj1), replacer) === JSON.stringify(sort(obj2), replacer);
}

const obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: { c: 1, d: 2 },
};
const obj2 = {
  b: { d: 2, c: 1 },
  a: 1,
};
const obj3 = {
  b: { d: 4, c: 3 },
  a: 1,
};
const obj4 = {
  a: 1,
  b: { c: 1, d: 2},
  c: undefined
}

console.log('1 == 2', compare(obj1, obj2)); // true
console.log('1 == 3', compare(obj1, obj3)); // false
// Edit: Handling a normally excluded value tyoe, i.e. undefined
console.log('1 == 4', compare(obj1, obj4)); // false




JSON.stringify is not a reliable solution. It will omit some keys, along with their key, when serialising. Consider compare( { a: 1, b: 2 },  { a: 1, b: 2, c: undefined }); (demo)

That's a good point and important to keep in mind. Whether this is a deal-breaker or not will ultimately depend on OP's use case and how the object is created.

@VLAZ I updated the answer to handle undefined values. JSON.stringify will also exclude functions and symbols, but I'll keep that impl. up to OP and their needs.

This works. I didn't consider just sticking with JSON.stringify() and sorting the object. Thanks!

I think you could cast your objects to an array, sort it by keys and re-cast it to your original object type. Then you‘d have the similar order of keys and can go ahead to hashing.
Here a more extensive answer from a similar question (not written by me)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069840/20932276

You cannot reliably "cast" an object to an array; you can certainly implement something that transforms certain kinds of objects important to a particular application, but in general the concept doesn't really make sense.
